# Demotion ? or Promotion?

Tags: human-resources, promotion

I started my employment a year ago as an Administrative Assistant

Within 3 months I was promoted to Payroll Administrator/ HR Assistant  (no experience but I excelled).

Within 7 months of my hire date I was promoted to HR Coordinator and replaced the HR Management position after my HR manager made a disaster and quit (at this point I had 4 months of HR experience but I was extremely excelling).  They did bring in their former HR manger who had been with the company for 10 years as my consultant and consultant for the Safety Coordinator.

Now after 9 months ( i know I have excelled, one of his few best workers busting ass 11 (and sometimes only claiming 9 hour days.... putting 150% in) since being HR Coordinator,), my boss informed me they would be firing my assistant and Safety Coordinator (they are extremely horrible at their job) and that my HR Consultant would becoming back full time. She would need an office, so I would have to give up my office and go back to my assistant desk.

My boss also stated that I am doing a wonderful job, nothing wrong with my performance and I would continue to do the work I am doing plus the work my assistant was doing ( So being someone's bitch again).

I am so confused and at a loss for words especially since my Consultant had a excellent job, she was working with her mother and was going to become director in about 3 years and also made her Best Friend go work for her about a year ago. It surprises me why she would leave so now (leave the wonderful medical field to come work for a barely making it rice mill field)

I am really questioning everything especially since he says I am doing a wonderful job. At this point, I am Wondering if I am even of value or they want me to become admin assistant forever. If that is the case I will be looking for a new job because I know my worth and what I bring to the table.

Any suggestions or thought would be nice?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace StackExchange. Hopefully you'll find the site useful. While I think there is a good question in your post, unfortunately,  it currently is a "wall of text" that is difficult to read and comes across as more rant than question. Please have a look through our [tour](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea of what sorts of questions to ask here and how to ask them. Then, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/70015/edit) your post so that it's a better fit within our guidelines.

Comment: It sounds like this boils down to: "my HR Consultant would becoming back full time so she would need an office so I would have to give up my office" - is that the issue? Can you make this easier to read (shorter paragraphs). Don't say "being someone's bitch again" if you want to be taken professionally.

Comment: Dont work 11h, you will burn out and your boss will expect you keep that level of perfomance. If your job load require 11h to be complete you may need one assistent.

Comment: Don't use your real name when complaining about your place of employment :)

Comment: Wall of text rant.

Comment: Made it LEDs wall-of-text. But I agree that in its current form it's a rant. The author should replace "what do you think" with an answerable question, at least... and frankly the history is mostly irrelevant; the core of the question is "after doing a good job as acting foo, how can I convince them that I deserve to be kept in a more senior position rather than returning to  the one I was hired into?"

Comment: "So being someone's bitch again" - that's exactly the kind of attitude and language I'd look for in an HR Coordinator.

Comment: During this time were you given any raises? Is your pay being scaled back?

Comment: C/LEDs/less/ in previous comment. Darned touchscreen...

Comment: From what you described it sounds like you are not losing any responsibilities rather you are just losing a assistant so you have to do their duties as well.  Having a office is a perk that this former employee may require coming back and if yours is the best one available I can see why they would ask you to move out of it.    Have you asked management what they view your role as going forward?

Comment: To go beyond the "this is a rant, I am not gonna help." comments, I would recommend that you define a clear & concise question and try to remove your emotion from the situation so there is a clear context. As far as a demotion is concerned, I would start looking at the turnover rate in the department (I worked in a HR dept with an even higher rate) ... needless to say I left promptly (hence "worked"). Don't be afraid to start looking considering you have some experience in various subsets of HR (note that on your resume/CV). Best of luck

Answer (score 7):

You mention several times that you don't have the training for the position you're currently in, and I think you musn't forget this fact.

The main function of the HR department is to limit the company's liability from a vast number of points of view. The former Manager is probably aware of legislation, policies, and procedures which you are not (I'm not saying that you wouldn't be able to learn these, but I am pointing out that you are not trained to her level).

From the company's point of view it makes a lot of sense to have her on board: their risk of being sued, or having a situation mishandled goes down the more experienced and trained their HR manager is. You were doing well, but represent a wild card. What if you make a mistake and they end up getting sued for not having a "qualified professional" handle sensitive staff information, etc? (this is speculation, but it's possible).

It's also possible that you needing this person's help as a consultant showed them that you are not quite ready for that level of responsibility yet (you still lack knowledge and experience).

Try to keep an open mind and not despair right off the bat!

This perceived demotion does not mean that they have a poor opinion of you, and indeed, you seem to have had a lot of opportunities in this company. You were hired as an assistant, and skyrocketed to the rank of HR coordinator within only 9 months. Most people take longer than that to figure their jobs, let along switch positions three times, and basically jump up to a management level position.

I suggest you do the following:

1. Have a very honest conversation with you boss. Tell him that you understand that you are not as experienced as X in the role, but want some feedback as to how you did, and whether it was poor performance on your part which spurred her being hired. Basically find out why you're being "demoted".
2. Ask your boss what their plans for you in the company are. (assuming that the answer to the previous question was relatively possible) Say that over the past 9 months you have demonstrated to yourself that you are capable of handling a lot more responsibility than you had thought, and that you are interested in being more than a simple office assistant. Underline that you are grateful to the organization for the opportunities given to you, and that you hope they will extend you the chance to further improve your skills, and rise within their ranks.

> **NOTE:** assuming the conversation is going well up to this point it would be a good time to inquire as to what your new position title is, and what your compensation is going to be.

4. Try not to be bitter working for this person (hopefully she appreciated how much responsibility you handled, has a good impression of you, and will treat you professionally, and with respect).  Try to learn as much from her as possible. Realize that 12 months at a company is an incredibly short time, and that leaving now would look very bad on your resume. Stick around for as long as you can (2 years, at least) and pick up as many skills as possible. Maybe take some HR courses - if that's what you're interested in getting into - and then seek a new job in that field rather than remain an assistant in this company.

Good luck!

Comment: Seconded.  Try to use this as an opportunity to get the training necessary for the job.  See if they'll send you to classes.  It's clear the company has a skills gap, here.  Maybe they're just waiting for someone to "Step up."  The OP seems to have the talent, but developing talent into skill takes time and effort.  OP should try for classes / certifications with assistance from the company.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want keep your office and your current title (HR Coordinator?), you should talk to the management about your concerns.

Also when you got promoted, did you sign a new contract? If you did, look in the contract to see what that entails - it might have the clause "other duties as assigned." This clause indicates that they can assign you to any other duties (assistant) even though your position has not officially changed.

Also, you need to bring the reasons of leaving out of this:

> I am so confused and at a loss for words especially since my Consultant had a excellent job, she was working with her mother and was going to become director in about 3 years and also made her Best Friend go work for her about a year ago.

That does not matter for the company. They are glad (I assume) that she is back and has given her job back. Your leverage point is that you are current and up to date on this job (and have done a good job), and you can continue to do it. That is what you should say to management.

Answer (score 1):

Please-please-please consider that, nobody can excel in any job in 10 or so months, even if they are on the job for 24 hours-a-day. You can learn the job and learn well, but considering your situation as "excelled" is a little bit of an exaggeration on your part. If this new person was there for a significantly longer period of time than yourself, he/she will know a lot more about the company, owners, work ethics and everything compared to you.

Instead of taking this as "*being someone's bitch again*", take it as a learning opportunity. Being on the job less than a year and getting praises from management is a very good start for a career. Since this person has left the company once before, likelihood of leaving one more time is not small. And if you have enough knowledge under your belt at that point, accompanied by a professional attitude, you might be a shoe-in replacement, when this event takes place.

Please understand, the company is not demoting you. They are keeping you at the same level. Your expectations are higher than what the company/supervisors perception of your role is. Unless you are working for mom/dad/uncle/aunt, it is very hard to get to a supervisory position in less than a year. In my opinion, you need to readjust your expectations. Don't forget, good things come to those who wait patiently.